# Setting up Eclipse for C++

Tags: c++, compilation, cygwin, header-files

I am trying to set up eclipse in order to compile and run C++ application.
I am using cygwing and I added it to the PATH on Eclipse. I created a new project with the default Hello World app.

```
#include "TryingCompile.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

TryingCompile::TryingCompile() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

TryingCompile::~TryingCompile() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    int value;
    cin>> value;
    cout << value;
    return 0;
}
```

The header file has not been provided by default but nevertheless it cimpiled but produced no output. Then I added header file.

```
#ifndef TRYINGCOMPILE_H_
#define TRYINGCOMPILE_H_

class TryingCompile {
public:
    TryingCompile();
    virtual ~TryingCompile();
};


#endif /* TRYINGCOMPILE_H_ */
```

It compiles but no output. Buy the way, binary file has been created. This is the first time I am setting up Eclipse for C++.
By the way, when you test the installation of cygwin on Windows cmd window typing in 'g++ -v' it does not recognize the command. But once you run the cygwin directly it produces installation details.
What is the problem with that?

Comment: Try running the executable in an external terminal window. If it works, you have to configure some kind of application input/output panel. I don't use Eclipse, but that's what I'd try if I were you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no output means it didn't complain, so everything went well.

perhaps you have to execute the binary by run it in a shell?